# Gradle in Intellij - Finding why an external library was imported

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

Pointing on an external library in Intellij,
is there a way to know why it was imported?
link it to a gradle import?

Comment: Any clues after running `gradle dependencies`? Otherwise, show us some code.

Comment: running it using the intellij plugin

Comment: It should give the same result either way, but you can open the Gradle tab (on right) and click the green "Execute Gradle Task" button to execute the task in IntelliJ.